# sympy's solve() command for equations != 0

Tags: sympy

As i've read in the sympy docs, the solve() command expects an equation to solve as being equal to zero.
As the equations i would like to solve are not in that form and in fact solving them for 0 is my purpose in using a library like sympy, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, so I hope my answer addresses what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the docs are saying is that if you do something like

```
>>> solve(x**2 - 1, x)
```

Then `solve` is implicitly assuming that `x**2 - 1` is equal to `0`.  If you wanted to solve `x**2 - 1 = 2`, then you could either subtract `2` from both sides, to get

```
>>> solve(x**2 - 1 - 2, x)
```

or you could use the `Eq()` class

```
>>> solve(Eq(x**2 - 1, 2), x)
```